# Antlr AST Tree Approach To Complex Grammar

Tags: java, antlr

I have written a complex grammar. The grammar can be seen below:

```
grammar i;

options {
output=AST;
}

@header {
package com.data;
}

operatorLogic   : 'AND' | 'OR';
value       : STRING;
query       : (select)*;
select      : 'SELECT'^ functions 'FROM table' filters?';';
operator    : '=' | '!=' | '<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=';
filters : 'WHERE'^ conditions;
conditions  : (members (operatorLogic members)*);
members : STRING operator value;
functions   : '*';
STRING  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
WS      : (' '|'\t'|'\f'|'\n'|'\r')+ {skip();}; // handle white space between keywords
```

The output is done using AST. The above is only a small sample. However, I am developing some big grammar and need advice on how to approach this.

For example according to the above grammar the following can be produced:

```
SELECT * from table;
SELECT * from table WHERE name = i AND name = j;
```

This query could get more complex. I have implemented AST in the Java code and can get the Tree back. I wanted to seperate the grammar and logic, so their are cohesive. So AST was the best approach.

The user will enter a query as a String and my code needs to handle the query in the best way possible. As you can see the functions parser currently is * which means select all. In the future this could expand to include other things.

How can my code handle this? What's the best approach?

I could do something like this:

```
String input = "SELECT * from table;";
if(input.startsWith("SELECT")) {
    select();
}
```

As you can see this approach is more complicated, as I need to handle * also the optional filters. The operatorLogic which is AND and OR, also needs to be done.

What is the best way? I have looked online, but couldn't find any example on how to handle this.

Are you able to give any examples?

EDIT:

```
String input = "SELECT * FROM table;";
if(input.startsWith("SELECT")) {
   select();
}
else if(input.startsWith("SELECT *")) {
  findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle multiple starting rules ("SELECT ...", "UPDATE...", etc) is to let the ANTLR grammar do the work for you at a single, top-level starting rule. You pretty much have that already, so it's just a matter of updating what you have.

Currently your grammar is limited to one command-type of input ("SELECT...") because that's all you've defined:

```
query       : (select)*; //query only handles "select" because that's all there is.
select      : 'SELECT'^ functions 'FROM table' filters?';';
```

If `query` is your starting rule, then accepting additional top-level input is a matter of defining `query` to accept more than `select`:

```
query       : (select | update)*; //query now handles any number of "select" or "update" rules, in any order.
select      : 'SELECT'^ functions 'FROM table' filters?';';
update      : 'UPDATE'^ ';';  //simple example of an update rule
```

Now the `query` rule can handle input such as `SELECT * FROM table;`, `UPDATE;`, or `SELECT * FROM table; UPDATE;`. When a new top-level rule is added, just update `query` to test for that new rule. This way your Java code doesn't need to test the input, it just calls the `query` rule and lets the parser handle the rest.

If you only want one type of input to be processed from the input, define `query` like this:

```
query       : select*  //read any number of selects, but no updates
            | update*  //read any number of updates, but no selects
            ;
```

The rule `query` still handles `SELECT * FROM table;` and `UPDATE;`, but not a mix of commands, like `SELECT * FROM table; UPDATE;`.

---

Once you get your `query_return` AST tree from calling `query`, you now have something meaningful that your Java code can process, instead of a string. That tree represents all the input that the parser processed.

You can walk through the children of the tree like so:

```
iParser.query_return r = parser.query();
CommonTree t = (CommonTree) r.getTree();

for (int i = 0, count = t.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    CommonTree child = (CommonTree) t.getChild(i);
    System.out.println("child type: " + child.getType());
    System.out.println("child text: " + child.getText());
    System.out.println("------");
}
```

Walking through the entire AST tree is a matter of recursively calling `getChild(...)` on all parent nodes (my example above looks at the top-level children only).

---

Handling alternatives to `*` is no different than any other alternatives you've defined: just define the alternatives in the rule you want to expand. If you want `functions` to accept more than `*`, define `functions` to accept more than `*`. ;)

Here's an example:

```
functions: '*'      //"all"
         | STRING   //some id
         ;
```

Now the parser can accept `SELECT * FROM table;` and `SELECT foobar FROM table;`.

Remember that your Java code has *no reason* to examine the input string. Whenever you're tempted to do that, look for a way to make your grammar do the examining instead. Your Java code will then look at the AST tree output for whatever it wants.

Comment: I am still confused. Actaully, the Lexer and Parser generates the query() which returns query_return as the return type. The problem is how will I know first of all, the the statement syntax is a query. For example, I could have other statements not of type query.

Comment: How can my Java code handle *, or other types. According to the examples I have provided. Would you do multiple if statements like I have shown. What is the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but this seems to not answer my question. 1) Once I retrieve the parsed token as *, is it best to handle in the way of multiple if statements. 2) How will my Java program know that that a query() is to be parsed. I could have a parser rule saying run, and I need to execute the run(). 3) You mentioned the Java code has no reason to examine the input string. Look for a way to make the grammar do the examing instead. Can you point me into the right direction? I am lost here.

Comment: According to your statement it seems, I should not hard code for example WHERE in the Java code. I am not sure of any other ideas.

Comment: @user1646481 The entire purpose of ANTLR is to take some input (e.g. the string "SELECT * FROM table;") and produce something that your code can more easily work with (e.g. a tree object with child node objects). Make sure you aren't doing ANTLR's job in your code.

Comment: Well, for example: * AND OR has specific meaning in my Java code. Where should this meaning be placed then and how? According, to my knowledge ANTLR is supposed to define the syntax and the parser parses to make sure it follows the syntax. The example code you have shown shows the parsing. How will I know which parser rule to execute depending on the input?

Comment: @user1646481 You won't know the parser rule because it's ANTLR's job to figure it out. You call the starting rule (e.g. `query`) and the parser processes the rules beneath `query` (`select` and `update`, in my answer). You can't separate syntax from the rules that define it, and you shouldn't want to try.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Just final thing: according to you I should avoid checking for strings like *, AND, OR, WHERE. How can I go about this. * means select all. How could I go about this in the code? As I have an optional filters. Should my code check against this? Can you please point me in the right direction. I am lost.

Comment: @user1646481 Look for "*", "AND", "OR", and "WHERE" nodes (and all the rest) in the tree that the parser produces. Run the `for` loop in my answer on some sample input and you'll see how things are stored there. Then make a recursive version of that code so that it prints all the nodes in the tree, and not just the top-level children. You'll want to get comfortable with how the data is stored in the tree and how to get at it because you'll be picking it apart looking for the information that you need.

Comment: I am comfortable with getting the nodes back. So, when I receive the node "*", my code can determine what that means. So it will be something like if node contains * then go and fetch everything from this table, otherwise if it contains any conditions such as WHERE then go and fetch accorinding to the conditions. 1) If this is the case, then it is a form of hard coding right? 2) What I am trying achieve is, the syntax is defined. Based on the input, the implementation of the Java code is done in the best way possible.

Comment: @user1646481 Yes, that's the general approach. The top of the tree will contain nodes (subtrees) that represent `select` and `update` commands. When you find a `select` node, for example, you could call `processSelect(CommonTree selectNode)` that you write to handle the details.

Comment: so this processSelect(CommonTree selectNode) I believe is something you have defined and not something from Antlr? I know CommonTree is in the Antlr API.

Comment: @user1646481 Correct, the method is just an example that you could write to do the work. Whatever you decide to use for methods, the code inside them would be whatever does the job for you.